# Use a separate consumer for throttling messages and publishing to main queue

Tags: apache-kafka

A method in my application causes a lot of messages (order of magnitude higher) to be published at once which can slow down processing for the rest of the application.

To prevent this from happening, I am planning to implement a separate background topic which only this method publishes the messages to, And then consume the messages from the background topic and publish them to the main queue in a batched and throttled manner.

I am looking to solicit advice on this approach, and whether there is a better way of achieving this.

Comment: Kafka doesn't have such a mechanism. You'd use high partition count to handle this appropriately... Otherwise, it's unclear how this background consumer wouldn't also be slow